# Is it possible to set a chart datasource from a generic list?

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, charts

I have a list created from a linq query that contains 2 columns of data.

```
var result = root.Descendants().Elements("sensor")
                 .Where(el => (string)el.Attribute("name") == "Sensor1") 
                 .Elements("evt") 
                 .Select(el => new { t1 = el.Attribute("time").Value, 
                                     v1 = el.Attribute("val").Value }) 
                 .ToList()
```

I'm trying to use the chart control datasource to use that list, but when I call the bind method I receive this error:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=Series data points do not support values of type
>   <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Double,System.Decimal] only values of
>   these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint,
>   ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.

```
//result is a generic list defined as var result = root.Descendants()
chart1.DataSource = result;
chart1.DataBind(); // This is line that causes the exception.
```

Regards.

Comment: We would need to see the linq.

Comment: `var result = root.Descendants()
                .Elements("sensor")
                .Where(el => (string)el.Attribute("name") == "Sensor1")
                .Elements("evt")
                .Select(el => new
                {       
                    t1 = el.Attribute("time").Value,
                    v1 = el.Attribute("val").Value
                })
                .ToList()`

Comment: I can display the data in a Datagrid, but unable to use the chart control.

Comment: See my updated answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but not by binding the list to the `Chart` itself.

There are several quite different methods to do [Chart Databinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), all with different sets of pros and cons..

I suggest using the [`Series.Points.DataBindXY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Series.Points.DataBind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.databind%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods.

Here is an example:

```
// create a list with test data:
List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) points.Add(new PointF(i, 1f * i / 2f * R.Next(8)));
```

Now create a generic list from it:

```
var al = points.Select(x => new { t1 = x.X, v1 = x.Y }).ToList();
```

Now this works:

```
someSeries.Points.DataBindXY(al, "t1", al, "v1");
```

or also this:

```
someSeries.DataBind(al, "t1", "v1", "" );
```

In your case you would write maybe this:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(result, "t1", "v1");
```

Note that a `Chart` typically can only display **pairs** of values whereas a `DGV` can create **as many columns** as the `DataSource` has. So `Chart` needs a little help in finding the x- and y-values..