# How to give two different dictionary value to stack-column chart

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, mschart

I have two dictionaries,  from which want to show stacked-column chart. I tried but don't understand where I am going wrong:

```
chartname.DataSource = EventcategoryopenCount;
chartname.Series["OPEN"].XValueMember = "Key";
chartname.Series["OPEN"].YValueMembers = "Value";
chartname.DataSource = EventcategoryreductCount;
chartname.Series["Close"].XValueMember = "Key";
chartname.Series["Close"].YValueMembers = "Value";
chartname.DataBind();
```

If I only use  one dictionary it creates output but when I am using both dictionaries nothing is showing in graph.

Comment: Why are you repeating the first 3 lines?

Comment: I had edited a code

Comment: I think you need to post more code. What kind of Chart is it? Why are you doing `chartname.DataSource = EventcategoryreductCount` twice?

Comment: We need to see or at least know more about the data. What types? What values? If you use more than one Series on a StackedColumn chartType they [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489221.aspx) should be [aligned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456707.aspx)  - See [here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744549/stacked-column-chart-in-c-sharp)!

Comment: I have only once used EventcategoryreductCount.  I have two dictionary, in both dictionary key is same but value is different. and i want that key to plot in graph. like IF I would take one dictionary key "march" so for that in EventcategoryopenCount dic. key will be 13 and for EventcategoryreductCount dic. key will be 12. so i want to plot them in one stack-column graph is it possible?

Comment: And the same number of values? Also: (And most importantly) You should __not bind to the chart but to the respective Series.Points__! Also: It is good practice to __first set the members and then the datasource__!

Comment: yes dictionary value will be same and with same in order but key value will be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a different way to do data binding if your two series shall have different datasources.

There are [several](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexgor/2009/02/20/data-binding-microsoft-chart-control/).. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750826/is-it-possible-to-set-a-chart-datasource-from-a-generic-list/37753965#37753965) is another post about a similar topic.)

You should not bind to the chart but to the **respective** `Series.Points`!

Change the code to:

```
chartname.Series["OPEN"].Points.DataBind(EventcategoryopenCount, "Key", "Value", "");
chartname.Series["Close"].Points.DataBind(EventcategoryreductCount, "Key", "Value", "");
```

Btw: It is good practice to first set the members and then the datasource but this method will do it both in one call..

Your data still need to be [aligned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456707.aspx).