# Clustered column chart in C# using Chart in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, column-chart

I would like to create a clustered column chart like the one shown in the image.

[image]

From my research, the best option is to use a DataTable to create this format in C#. However, I have a List of my BoardYield Class (List) which contains members such as monthly passCount, failCount, monthlyYieldPercentage, overallYield, and other such members.

I would like to create a clustered column chart that has a quarterly or monthly breakdown for different board part numbers. I would like to format my Chart Series such that I can use my List list and get the data to look like the image without switching to a DataTable.

Do I have an option for this? How would I format my Series using a List to create a chart as shown?

Thank you!

Comment: As you can see from the legend this chart has __four series__. The clustering around the common x-values happens automatically. You can use any datasource, not just a datatable; just bind to the `Points` of __each series__ using the respective member names! [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750826/is-it-possible-to-set-a-chart-datasource-from-a-generic-list/37753965#37753965)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have yet to try this implementation. I will see how it goes.